# Linux C how to get a !eof event?

Tags: c, eof

i want to watch a file fd is readable when not eof in linux c.
now i have to loop until !eof,i think it's waste of cpu time.

```
static int rs_eof_read_binlog(rs_master_info_t *m, void *buf, 
    size_t size) {

FILE *fp;
size_t n;

fp = m->bfp;
for( ;; ) {
    n = fread(buf, size, 1, fp);
    if(n * size < size) {
        if(ferror(fp) != 0) {
            return RS_ERR;
        }

        if(feof(fp) != 0) {
            fseek(fp, -n * size, SEEK_CUR);
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}

clearerr(fp);
return RS_OK;
```

}

i checkd the select,when a file eof ,select returns.

```
Those listed in readfds will be watched to see if characters become avail‐
   able  for reading (more precisely, to see if a read will not block; in particular, a file descriptor is also ready on end-of-file)
```

fixed!!!!
sample code use inotify

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

{

```
char p, buf[1024];
int fd = open("/home/terry/1.txt", O_RDONLY, "00666");
struct inotify_event * event;
size_t len;

read(fd, &p, 1);

int ifd = inotify_init();
int wd = inotify_add_watch(ifd, "/home/terry/1.txt", IN_MODIFY);
while(len = read(ifd, buf, 1024)) {
    event = (struct inotify_event *) buf;
    if(event->mask & IN_MODIFY) {
        printf("changed\n");
        break;
    }
}



return 0;
```

}

Comment: Considering you're not using `select` anywhere in this code, and don't even have an fd_set you're passing anywhere, what makes you think that anything you read in `man select` applies?

Comment: @cHao, I guess he tries to explain why he can't use `select` - he wants to know when there's data, but `select` would wake him up at EOF.

Comment: @ugoren: Well, then, he needs to be a bit clearer about that.  I'm not sure `select` would do what he wants anyway on a file -- it's meant more for pipes and sockets.

Comment: @cHao  i explained why i can't use select .

Comment: @Terry: Not very well, you didn't.  I'm not even understanding why you even thought it'd be an option.  It's only useful when you want to block until the FD is ready -- in which case, you don't even need it for a file.  A read on a file at EOF would read 0 bytes and set the EOF status.

Comment: @cHao  emm. i think when file eof,select will block,unitl file write or access by othes.so i try to use select ,but after man select ,i found when file eof select also set FD is ready ..,now i try to use inotify...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the `inotify` mechanism.
Use `inotify_add_watch` to listen to the `IN_MODIFY` event on the file you want to watch.

Comment: i get this : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cn/linux/l-inotifynew/  thks a lot...~

Comment: @Terry, your link is like Chinese for me... But whatever works for you.